# Symmetry in surface integrals on spheres

Tags: surface-integrals

I stumbled upon an example on surface integrals that uses symmetry, and I feel like I'm missing something that *should* be simple. We're dealing with a sphere $\Sigma_R$ centered on the origin with radius R. Halfway through the example, we're met with what is described as simple symmetry reasoning. (I'm sure it is, I just wish they'd described it better.)

$$
\iint_{\Sigma_R} x_1x_2 dS = \iint_{\Sigma_R} x_2 x_3 dS = 0
$$

Where $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are the input variables, and S is the surface segment of the sphere. What I'm not sure about is *how* we can know that these integrals are symmetric. I understand *why* a symmetric integral would be zero, but as far as I know, symmetry happens with odd functions, whereas these are (as far as I can tell, even).

Help me, StackExchange. You're my only hope.

Comment: If you wish to formalize the symmetry reasoning_: what appens to the first integral after you have applied the transformation $$\begin{cases}x_1'=x_3\\x_2'=x_2\\x_3'=x_1\end{cases}$$?